# SQL 2000/2005/2008 - Find Unique Constraint Name for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a table with a column that needs the data type upgrading.  However running any alter script causes errors due to a unnamed unique constraint.

I need to drop this constraint but unfortunately I do not know the name.  I have a script which currently lists all the unique constraints on the table but I need to find out how to go that one step further and associate the constraint names with the columns.

```
Select *
From sysobjects
Where sysobjects.xtype = 'UQ' AND sysobjects.parent_obj= OBJECT_ID(N'Users')
```

this returns

```
UQ__Users__45F365D3
UQ__Users__46E78AOC
```

I need to know which columns theses are linked to in order to delete the right one.  I need to support SQL 2000, 2005, and 2008.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE to establish this.

```
SELECT 
   CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'
```

Not certain whether the view is fully supported in SQL 2000 though.

Comment: Thanks JamWheel.  This seems to work fine and as expected on SQL 2000, 2005, and 2008!

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This did not work for me to find a default constraint; it only located the FK constraint.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883039/109736 worked for me.